# LightDm starting with black screen, but works fine after switching

Tags: boot, unity, lightdm

I am getting black screen when I boot. Waiting doesn't give any changes. If I press Alt + Ctrl + F1 and switch back to the Lightdm graphical mode by Alt + Ctrl + F7, the screen is shown now.

Why is lightdm not starting normally before I make a switch?

Thanks

Comment: is this issue related to some specific hardware or are you experiencing it on some sort of virtualisation?

Comment: it is not virtualisation.